# Treating underscore as delimiter in SharePoint search results

Tags: 2007, search

What is the best way to treat an underscore "_" as a delimiter in a SharePoint 2007 environment (MOSS2007 Enterprise)?
For example, if we have got files that are named PricingConditions_UK_2011.docx, PricingConditions_Germany_2011.docx, 2011_France_PricingConditions.docx, I want to be able to find these files through their filename by searching for PricingConditions.

While I would agree that in a perfect world there'd be spaces here and lots of appropriate metadata, this is not a solution that is feasible for us. So we really want to treat the underscore as a delimiter. I was hoping to find a simple word breaker solution that we could implement, but either I didn't find it or there seems to be none?

Answer (score 1):

afaik no there isn't :( but I'm not Bruce AlMighty