# Underscores in SharePoint List Search don't work

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, form-library

Why does the inline SharePoint list search not work with underscores? For example, in a Form Library searching for a file, if I type `2015-06-26 20_50_58` no results are found, however if I type `2015-06-26 20 50 58` it works.

[image]

Comment: There is also an old SP2007 related question about turning the underscores into a delimiter [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/treating-underscore-as-delimiter-in-sharepoint-search-results).

Comment: are you using the foundation or Server version?

Comment: Server version.